# Segmentation fault in online compilers

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

The code below works fine in gdb and VS code but other online compilers keep throwing "segmentation fault". Can anyone please help me with this? Every question I try to solve I keep getting this error.

For example:
`Given an array of integers. Find the Inversion Count in the array.`

Inversion Count: For an array, inversion count indicates how far (or close) the array is from being sorted. If the array is already sorted then the inversion count is 0. If an array is sorted in the reverse order then the inversion count is the maximum.

Formally, two elements a[i] and a[j] form an inversion if a[i] > a[j] and i < j.

Code:

```cpp
long long int inversionCount(long long arr[], long long N) {
    vector<long long> v; 
    long long int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) v[i]= arr[i];

    auto min = min_element(arr, arr+ N);
    auto max = max_element(arr, arr+ N);
    swap(v[0], *min);
    v.erase(max);
    v.push_back(*max);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if(v[i] > v[i+1]) {
            swap(v[i],v[i+1]);
            count++;
        }
        return count; 
    }
}
```

Comment: `v[i+1]` looks suspicious when i is N-1.

Comment: You either need to allocate space in `v` or use `push_back`.

Comment: The first loop in your function has undefined behaviour if `N` is greater than zero, since `v` has size zero.  `v[i] = arr[i]` will access and modify non-existent elements of `v`.    The fact it seems to work with some compilers doesn't mean it is valid.   One of the dangers of undefined behaviour is that "seems to work,with some compilers, and not with others" is a perfectly valid outcome.  Most of the following operations on `v` ASSUME it has valid elements, when it doesn't, so also contribute their own share of undefined behaviour.

Comment: One of the properties of undefined behaviour is "no diagnostics required" - particularly relevant when the cause of undefined behaviour is due to input data at run time, which - by definition - a compiler cannot diagnose.   So such code can compile happily, but the results at run time can be anything (seeming to work "correctly", crashing, or anything else).

Comment: "works fine" This is an incredibly hard to believe statement.

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of problems here. For one, you try to use elements in `v` without ever allocating space for them (i.e., you're using subscripts to refer to elements of `v` even though its size is still zero elements. I'd usually use the constructor that takes two iterators to copy an existing collection (and pointers can be iterators too).

```cpp
std::vector<long long> v { arr, arr+N};
```

Assuming you fix that, this:

```
         v.erase(max);
```

... invalidates `max` and every other iterator or reference to any point between the element `max` previously pointed to, and the end of the collection. Which means that this:

```
         v.push_back(*max);
```

...is attempting to dereference an invalid iterator, which produces undefined behavior.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'll try my best to understand your reply and implement it. Just one more question : why did this compile fine in vs code?

Comment: @man-a-v: undefined behavior can look/act like you expect, but then fail for unexplained reasons at arbitrary times, such as when you're giving a demo for your biggest potential customer...

Comment: @man-a-v - you have undefined behavior, you are stomping all over memory, sometimes you hit harmless stuff, other times not . You experienced the worst kind of UB, the code seemed to work. It will fail at midnight on the busiest day for your company.

Comment: @man-a-v SO answerers knew right away it was UB when you said your code ran on some platforms but crashed hard on others, before even looking at the code

Comment: The part with the _demo for your biggest potential customer_ is precisely what I experience myself... ;-)